# Div is too small and text overcome

Tags: html, css, asp.net, overflow

I'm working on my ASP.NET project (written in C#).

I can't code `div` to have the correct size for the text inside him. I want to have a `div` to capture the text well and resize itself when I shrink the page.

Can somebody help me, please?

[Here is a photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgqAs.jpg) with what happens.

Css code:

```css
.box {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #e0e4e8;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 100px;
    color: #717171;
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
}
```

Html code:

```
<div class="box">
  <p class="date">Datele contului</p>
  <br />
  <table class="profil">
    <tr>
      <td>Nume:</td>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblNume" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Prenume:</td>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblPrenume" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email:</td>
      <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lblEmail" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr />
</div>
```

Comment: The only one thing you have to do is to remove height values from css.
Despite the fact that you override it twice block element is as high as it content need

Comment: don't works.   Look: https://imgur.com/a/alGuax3

Comment: Have you removed both values of height?

Comment: I did it. Now, work. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove the height attribute in css. (or)
Try Setting height to auto.

You have set height twice in your css. Remove Both.

Comment: Thank you! I don't saw that are 2 heights... My fault.

Comment: Welcome! Accept it as the answer so the question will be closed. Have a good day!